# Error passing time value in URL javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm creating a phonegap app, and in a page I have for example a URL url.com/time=10:10&name=Charles and in a Galaxy Tab 3 I've this error:

```
07-28 22:12:17.023: A/libc(26130): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 26143 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

If url.com/time=&name=Charles the process is OK, the problem is with the ":" :(

Thanks!

Comment: Does `url.com/?time=10%3A10&name=Charles` work?

Comment: yes! I use this function function getUrlVars() {
    var url = window.location.href,
        vars = {};
    url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
         key = decodeURIComponent(key);
         value = decodeURIComponent(value);
         vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

Comment: Then you need to use `encodeURIComponent()`. Bollis provides an answer that should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try encoding the string first

[encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: I'm using decodeURIComponent(), I don't know where to use, this is my funciton function getUrlVars() {
    var url = window.location.href,
        vars = {};
    url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
         key = decodeURIComponent(key);
         value = decodeURIComponent(value);
         vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

Comment: So you are using this function to get an array of the current url vars, once you are already on the desired page?? Can you encode the url on the original page? encodeURIComponent() will encode the ":" symbol for you.

Comment: My mistake was don't encode the url on the original page :/